# Is the set $ {\rm SL }(n, \mathbb {R}) $ connected in ${\rm M }(n, \mathbb {R}) $

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, connectedness

Is the set $ {\rm SL }(n, \mathbb {R}) $ connected in ${\rm M }(n, \mathbb {R}) $?

Can you  give me hints? I have only concept on  following tags.

Answer (score 10):

The answer is yes, and it is even pathwise connected. But it requires some minimal knowledge in linear algebra. An easy way is to use the fact that the group $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is generated by transvections=elementary matrices. Then each such matrix can easily be connected to $I_n$ within $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Indeed, let $T=I_n+\lambda E_{i,j}$ be an elementary matrix (diagonal of $1$'s and a unique possibly nonzero off-diagonal coefficient $\lambda$ in $(i,j)$ position for some $i\neq j$. Then
$$
T_t:=I_n+t\lambda E_{i,j}
$$
defines a path connecting $T$ and $I_n$ with $\det T_t=1$ for every $t$.

**Related:** see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315356/prove-that-the-set-of-n-by-n-real-matrices-with-positive-determinant-is-conn) for many proofs of the fact that the set of  real square matrices with positive determinant is pathwise connected, hence connected. Note that it implies the case of $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$. Indeed, if $S$ has determinant and if $S_t$ is a path connecting $S$ to $I_n$ within the matrices of positive determinant, then
$$
\widetilde{S_t}:=\frac{S_t}{\sqrt[n]{\det S_t}}
$$
connects $S$ and $I_n$ within $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative proof of connectedness if you don't mind using something less elementary.

Let $A=USV^T$ be a [singular value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) over $\mathbb{R}$. As $\det A=1$, we may assume WLOG that $\det U=\det V=1$ and hence $U=e^{K_1}$ and $V=e^{K_2}$ for some skew symmetric matrices $K_1,K_2$. Let $S=\operatorname{diag}(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_n)$. Then $I$ is pathwise connected to $A$ via the path
$$f(t)=e^{tK_1}\operatorname{diag}(\sigma_1^t,\sigma_2^t,\ldots,\sigma_n^t)e^{-tK_2}.$$