# Understanding that $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ has two connected components

Tags: general-topology, matrices, lie-groups

I am trying to understand the proof of the theorem:

> $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ has two components.

The proof says that

> The group of matrices with positive and negative determinant, $GL_n(\mathbb{R})_+$ and $GL_n(\mathbb{R})_-$, respectively are homeomorphic open subsets of $GL_n(\mathbb{R}).$  So it suffices to prove that $GL_n(\mathbb{R})_+$ is connected.

I don't understand why they are homeomorphic and open. Could you help me?

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: oh, I have edited my question.

Comment: you see this should make sense for $n=1$? Do you see that $Gl_n(\mathbb{R})$ is disconnected?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315356/prove-that-the-set-of-n-by-n-real-matrices-with-positive-determinant-is-conn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the determinant map $\det\colon GL_n(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$. This is a continuous map, so the inverse image of an open set is open. Note that $GL_n(\mathbb{R})_+ = \det^{-1}((0,\infty))$ and $GL_n(\mathbb{R})_- =\det^{-1}((-\infty, 0))$ are inverse images of open sets, thus they are open.

Why are they homeomorphic? Well let's construct a homeomorphism between them. Take $f\colon GL_n(\mathbb{R})_+\to GL_n(\mathbb{R})_-$ to be the map which takes a matrix $M\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})_+$ and sends it to $AM$, where $A$ is the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $(-1,1,1,\ldots, 1)$. Note that $\det (A) = -1$, so $\det(AM) = -\det(M)$. In particular $AM\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})_-$, so indeed $f$ maps $GL_n(\mathbb{R})_+$ into $GL_n(\mathbb{R})_-$. Can you see why $f$ is a homeomorphism? What is its inverse?

Comment: Thank you. I see only the bijection. Why are $f,f^{-1}$ cont's? Is it true by definition given that $f,f^{-1}$ maps open set to open set?

Comment: Forget for a minute that these are matrices, and instead think of them as elements of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, coordinatewise. From this perspective, $f$ is just a polynomial map $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}\to \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. I think you know that polynomial maps are continuous....

Comment: oh yes, I now see it. Thanks so much. : )

Answer (score 4):

$\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ does not contain matrices with determinant zero.  This leaves some matrices with positive determinants and some with negative determinants.  If these are each connected open sets, then they form a separation of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$, so the whole thing cannot be connected.

Consider that any matrix with positive determinant can be converted to one with negative determinant by multiplying the first row (or column) by $-1$, giving an easy way to show a bijection.  (Showing it's a homeomorphism is only a bit more work.)

Open...  Let $P = \{M \mid \det M > 0\}$ and consider $f:P \rightarrow \mathbb{R}:M \rightarrow \det M$.  If you believe this is a continuous function then we observe that $f(P) = (0, \infty)$, which is open, so the preimage, $P$, is open.  To show that it is continuous, (I abbreviate:) small changes in the matrix entries cause small changes in the determinant.